# How do production packages work when used inside a --save-dev package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux

I am working through a [React Redux course](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part6/many_reducers#redux-dev-tools) and we installed Redux devtools using `npm install --save-dev redux-devtools-extension` and used it like this:

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  composeWithDevTools()
)
```

My understanding is the `--save-dev` flag means this package won't be used in production. The next section of the course introduces Redux Thunk and is installed using `npm install redux-thunk`. If I am not mistaken, this means this package will be used in production. However, thunk is used in the course like this:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
)
```

thunk is used inside a package function that was installed using `--save-dev`. How would this work in production since that version would not install *redux-devtools-extension*?

Comment: These packages are likely being bundled by Webpack at _build_ time - strictly, there are no runtime production dependencies in that case, you're serving static files.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, libraries are included in your bundle if they are referenced in your code. That's all it takes. Separating them into `dependencies` or `devDependencies` is still, in my opinion, a good practice to keep things a bit more organized. So technically, even if you have for example `webpack` in `dependencies` it won't be bundled because you wouldn't import webpack in your app.

Comment: If you want more control, you can always put certain imports (technically `require()`) inside `if (process.env.node_env === 'production')` (or "development") clauses.

Answer (score 0):

--save-dev adds the third-party package to the package's development dependencies. It won't be installed when someone runs npm install directly to install your package. It's typically only installed if someone clones your source repository first and then runs npm install in it.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer is **no**, it should not work in production. When you installed a dependency in dev mode, then it should only meant for development purpose. As you installed the dependencies via `--save-dev` flag, the dependencies will not bundle into production code. Since you have included your dependencies in your code without any conditional statement (if statement) to determine whether or not you are in development mode and you have installed the dependency in dev mode only, the code already breaks at

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
```

If you really want to use the dev tools only in dev environment, install it in not dev mode and use the following import statement:

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';
```

Meanwhile if you only want to use it in production, import this.

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/logOnlyInProduction';
```

And if you want to use this dev tools in either way, then you may use back the first import statement as it will not check for your environment.

If the first statement is working fine for the production environment, then there will be no point for the author/collaborator to include the developmentOnly and logOnlyInProduction variant in the source code of the library.

The difference of each variant is available in the src code:

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/c220fd18d6fb4b0790a501ec4df0de52b5bee460/npm-package/logOnly.js#L40

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/npm-package/developmentOnly.js

https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/npm-package/logOnlyInProduction.js